# List Validation for Multiple Unrelated Conditions (one user message)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am a newbee and hope you can help me as I've read many other posts and still stuck.

I have multiple conditions that are unrelated and attempting to add the proper formula to the validation settings of my SP list.

This is the formula I have working so far for 2 conditions:

```
=IF([CRAIDL Type]="Risk",IF(Priority<>"",IF(Status="Closed",IF([Closed Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),FALSE),FALSE),FALSE)
```

How can I nest these other conditions from this formula?
-Require [Priority] for other CRAIDL types in addition to risk: Action, Issue, and Discovery.

- If [Status] is "open", "in progress", or "ready to test", the [next review date] should NOT be blank & [CLOSED DATE] should be blank.

One user message for all is ok; I'm trying to avoid Power Apps. TIA!

Comment: Could you define your validation in a simple "AND" and "OR" conditions? You can take a look at this [formula reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)) to see how to construct formula using AND/OR

Comment: Thank you for commenting.  I reviewed that link before posting and was unable to solve but could be due to my newness. 

If CRAIDL Type= ___(there's 4 of them), the Priority field must be populated (not blank).Also, if Status selection is OPEN, In Progress, or Ready to test, one field (next review date) should NOT be blank and another (closed date) should be blank.  I'm trying to figure out how all of this gets nested with the proper syntax.

Comment: Sure.. no worries. Will post my response little later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AND function to nest mulitple conditions.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-9ca21054-a466-477e-98bf-fc79e62afb3c

> Syntax
>
> AND(logical1,logical2,…)
>
> Logical1,Logical2,…    are 1 to 30 conditions you want to test that
> can be either TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Thanks, I did review that and try to apply it but continue to get syntax errors as I'm not building the formula correctly, so hoping you professionals know how to nest these rules together properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your requirements, here is the formula that you can try.
Please note that you need to update the column names and choice column values to match your list.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(CRAIDLType)),IF(ISBLANK(Priority),FALSE,IF(OR(OR(Status="Open",Status="In Progress"),Status="Ready to Test"),IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(NextReviewDate)),ISBLANK(ClosedDate)),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)),TRUE)
```

[image]

[image]

**Valid Entry**

[image]

**Updated formula** based on the updated requirements:

```
Pattern to use: =IF( OR( NOT(Formula1), NOT(Formula2), NOT(Formula3), NOT(Formula4) ),FALSE,TRUE)

Updated formula:

=IF( OR( NOT(IF(OR([CRAIDL Type] ="Risk",[CRAIDL Type] ="Action",[CRAIDL Type] ="Discovery",[CRAIDL Type] ="Issue"),IF([Priority]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)), NOT(IF(Status="Closed",IF([Closed Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)), NOT(IF(OR([Status] ="Open",[CRAIDL Type] ="In Progress",[CRAIDL Type] ="Ready for Retest ISSUE”),IF([Next Review Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)), NOT(IF(OR([Status] ="Open",[Status] ="In Progress",[Status] ="Ready for Retest ISSUE”),IF([Closed Date]="",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)) ),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, I updated my column names accordingly using your formula but resulted in a syntax error.

Comment: Can you post the formula with the updated column names? I will see if there is any syntax error after you have updated the column names. Also, make sure the column names are correct.

Comment: Thanks.. I've gotten these 4 formulas to work successfully on their own.  How do I combine them?  In other words, all 4 validations should be applied, if any of these 4 are false, return the one error. I'll post each formula in a separate comment as characters are limited.

Comment: =IF(OR([CRAIDL Type] ="Risk",[CRAIDL Type] ="Action",[CRAIDL Type] ="Discovery",[CRAIDL Type] ="Issue"),IF([Priority]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

Comment: =IF(Status="Closed",IF([Closed Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

Comment: =IF(OR([Status] ="Open",[CRAIDL Type] ="In Progress",[CRAIDL Type] ="Ready for Retest ISSUE”),IF([Next Review Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

Comment: =IF(OR([Status] ="Open",[Status] ="In Progress",[Status] ="Ready for Retest ISSUE”),IF([Closed Date]="",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

Comment: The pattern that you can used is: `=IF( OR( NOT(Formula1), NOT(Formula2), NOT(Formula3), NOT(Formula4) ),FALSE,TRUE)` replace Formula1, Formula2, Formula3, and Formula4. Basically, if any of the formulas returns FALSE, an error msg will be thrown. I'm going to post the update formula in my original post

Comment: I figured it out!  Thank you all for trying to help. 

=IF(AND([CRAIDL Type] ="Risk",[CRAIDL Type] ="Action",[CRAIDL Type] ="Discovery",[CRAIDL Type] ="Issue"),IF([Priority]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),IF(Status="Closed",IF([Closed Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),IF(OR([Status] ="Open",[CRAIDL Type] ="In Progress",[CRAIDL Type] ="Ready for Retest ISSUE”),IF([Next Review Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),IF(OR([Status] ="Open",[Status] ="In Progress",[Status] ="Ready for Retest ISSUE”),IF([Closed Date]="",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE))))